# How to find out what the Cinnamon process does

Tags: linux, cinnamon, debugging

I would like to identify what draws power in Cinnamon (the process not the entire desktop) aka what eats the cpu and causes the context switches. It is not about finding out what draws power overall on my machine.

Any good tips how to help the project here?

Comment: `htop`? <filler text>

Comment: Are you looking inside one process or are you looking for the highest-energy processes? Have you explored powertop?

Comment: It is about looking into the process to figure out why it is busy and draws power.

Answer (score 0):

The command line tool `top` will show you a list of processes and their cumulative cpu consumption. You can change the sort column with `<` and `>`. read `man top` for more options. Some things that run intermittently from cron (like `apt-get update`) won't show in top while they are not running.

Comment: I know atop, top, htop, powertop, iotop and all these. I know what process consumes the power. I want to figure out the why, aka what does this process do the entire time even though I am not doing anything.

Comment: Then list your top 3 cpu consumers and we will tell you what they are likely up to or you can read the man pages and source code to figure it out yourself. Please update you question to reflect what you actually want to know eg; 'why is ntpd using so much cpu?'